# I need to use a variable to iterate through inserting into recordsets, but don't know how to do it

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to iterate through inserting values into fields in a table.  I have tried using the code below (code like it, I generalized below), but it give me a Runtime error# 3265: "Item not found in this collection."  Any ideas how to accomplish this?

```
Private Sub ImportRWPData_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim File As Field
    Dim Location As String
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("rwpT")
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("AIP&BOP")
    Set File = rs.Fields("File")
    Dim xls As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Set xls = New Excel.Application

   'Declare variables for column values in RWP spreadsheets
    Dim orgSheetCol(7) As String
    orgSheetCol(0) = "$A$" 'Auto Isolation Point
    orgSheetCol(1) = "$D$" 'Customer Minutes Lost
    orgSheetCol(2) = "$H$" '% work plan fix
    orgSheetCol(3) = "$E$" 'Customers in Incident Sustained
    orgSheetCol(4) = "$C3$" 'Plan Title
    orgSheetCol(5) = "$B33$" 'Years of Data
    orgSheetCol(6) = "$B37$" 'Annual Improved CML
    'Declare variables for cell values attained from RWP spreadsheets
    Dim RWPSheetvalues(100) As String
    RWPSheetvalues(0) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 1
    RWPSheetvalues(1) = "" 'CML for Point 1
    RWPSheetvalues(2) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(3) = "" 'CI For Point 1
    RWPSheetvalues(4) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 2
    RWPSheetvalues(5) = "" 'CML for Point 2
    RWPSheetvalues(6) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(7) = "" 'CI For Point 2
    RWPSheetvalues(8) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 3
    RWPSheetvalues(9) = "" 'CML for Point 3
    RWPSheetvalues(10) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(11) = "" 'CI For Point 3
    RWPSheetvalues(12) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 4
    RWPSheetvalues(13) = "" 'CML for Point 4
    RWPSheetvalues(14) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(15) = "" 'CI For Point 4
    RWPSheetvalues(16) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 5
    RWPSheetvalues(17) = "" 'CML for Point 5
    RWPSheetvalues(18) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(19) = "" 'CI For Point 5
    RWPSheetvalues(20) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 6
    RWPSheetvalues(21) = "" 'CML for Point 6
    RWPSheetvalues(22) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(23) = "" 'CI For Point 6
    RWPSheetvalues(24) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 7
    RWPSheetvalues(25) = "" 'CML for Point 7
    RWPSheetvalues(26) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(27) = "" 'CI For Point 7
    RWPSheetvalues(28) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 8
    RWPSheetvalues(29) = "" 'CML for Point 8
    RWPSheetvalues(30) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(31) = "" 'CI For Point 8
    RWPSheetvalues(32) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 9
    RWPSheetvalues(33) = "" 'CML for Point 9
    RWPSheetvalues(34) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(35) = "" 'CI For Point 9
    RWPSheetvalues(36) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 10
    RWPSheetvalues(37) = "" 'CML for Point 10
    RWPSheetvalues(38) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(39) = "" 'CI For Point 10
    RWPSheetvalues(40) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 11
    RWPSheetvalues(41) = "" 'CML for Point 11
    RWPSheetvalues(42) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(43) = "" 'CI For Point 11
    RWPSheetvalues(44) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 12
    RWPSheetvalues(45) = "" 'CML for Point 12
    RWPSheetvalues(46) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(47) = "" 'CI For Point 12
    RWPSheetvalues(48) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 13
    RWPSheetvalues(49) = "" 'CML for Point 13
    RWPSheetvalues(50) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(51) = "" 'CI For Point 13
    RWPSheetvalues(52) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 14
    RWPSheetvalues(53) = "" 'CML for Point 14
    RWPSheetvalues(54) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(55) = "" 'CI For Point 14
    RWPSheetvalues(56) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 15
    RWPSheetvalues(57) = "" 'CML for Point 15
    RWPSheetvalues(58) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(59) = "" 'CI For Point 15
    RWPSheetvalues(60) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 16
    RWPSheetvalues(61) = "" 'CML for Point 16
    RWPSheetvalues(62) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(63) = "" 'CI For Point 16
    RWPSheetvalues(64) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 17
    RWPSheetvalues(65) = "" 'CML for Point 17
    RWPSheetvalues(66) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(67) = "" 'CI For Point 17
    RWPSheetvalues(68) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 18
    RWPSheetvalues(69) = "" 'CML for Point 18
    RWPSheetvalues(70) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(71) = "" 'CI For Point 18
    RWPSheetvalues(72) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 19
    RWPSheetvalues(73) = "" 'CML for Point 19
    RWPSheetvalues(74) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(75) = "" 'CI For Point 19
    RWPSheetvalues(76) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 20
    RWPSheetvalues(77) = "" 'CML for Point 20
    RWPSheetvalues(78) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(79) = "" 'CI For Point 20
    RWPSheetvalues(80) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 21
    RWPSheetvalues(81) = "" 'CML for Point 21
    RWPSheetvalues(82) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(83) = "" 'CI For Point 21
    RWPSheetvalues(84) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 22
    RWPSheetvalues(85) = "" 'CML for Point 22
    RWPSheetvalues(86) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(87) = "" 'CI For Point 22
    RWPSheetvalues(88) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 23
    RWPSheetvalues(89) = "" 'CML for Point 23
    RWPSheetvalues(90) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(91) = "" 'CI For Point 23
    RWPSheetvalues(92) = "" 'Autoisolation Point 24
    RWPSheetvalues(93) = "" 'CML for Point 24
    RWPSheetvalues(94) = "" '% Work Plan Fix
    RWPSheetvalues(95) = "" 'CI For Point 25
    RWPSheetvalues(96) = "" 'Plan Title
    RWPSheetvalues(97) = "" 'File Location
    RWPSheetvalues(98) = "" 'Years of Data
    RWPSheetvalues(99) = "" 'Annual Improved CML        
    Dim cellstring As String
    Dim rowstring As String
    Dim rownumber As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer
    rowstring = CStr(rownumber)
    Dim Mycheck As String
    Dim x As String  
    Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open(Location, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Benefit of Plan")
    ii = 0
    For rownumber = 7 To 30
        rowstring = CStr(rownumber)
            For i = 0 To 3
            cellstring = orgSheetCol(i) & rowstring
            RWPSheetvalues(ii) = wks.Range(cellstring).Value
            Mycheck = VarType(RWPSheetvalues(ii))
            ii = ii + 1
            Dim x As String
            Next i
        Next rownumber
    RWPSheetvalues(96) = wks.Range("C3").Value
    RWPSheetvalues(97) = File
    RWPSheetvalues(98) = wks.Range("B33").Value
    RWPSheetvalues(99) = wks.Range("B37").Value    
    tablecheck = DCount("PlanTitle", "AIP&BOP", "PlanTitle = '" & RWPSheetvalues(71) & "'") 'check AIP & BOP table to see if plan is already there
    If tablecheck = 0 Then
        rs2.AddNew
        rs2!PlanTitle.Value = RWPSheetvalues(96)
        rs2!FileLocation.Value = RWPSheetvalues(97)
        rs2!YearsofData.Value = CInt(RWPSheetvalues(98))
        rs2!AnnualImprovedCML.Value = CLng(RWPSheetvalues(99))
            For i = 0 To 95
                If RWPSheetvalues(i) <> "" Then
                    x = "AIP" & i + 1 'It Errors on this line
                    rs2!x.Value = RWPSheetvalues(0)
                End If
            Next i
    End If
    wkb.Close False 'Close workbook.  False is so that it doesn't save
    'rs.MoveNext
    'Wend
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the full code, and include which line causes the error. It sounds to me like `RWPSheetvalues` doesn't contain one of those `i` values.

Comment: Here's the full code, but it includes a lot of stuff that I am trying...

Comment: Actually, I amended the text in the orginal question to include the code...

Comment: That's a really strange error to receive on that line. I almost can't believe it. Perhaps `x = "AIP" & (i + 1)` to force the addition to take place before the concatenation?

Comment: I wish it weren't so, but that's what I get.  I tried x = "AIP" & (I+1) and it still doesn't work.  The variable x does contain the value (AIP1), but still craps out on the line: rs2!x.value = RWPSheetvalues(0)...

Answer (score 0):

```
rs2!x.Value = RWPSheetvalues(0)
```

tries to assign a value to the literal column `x`, hence the error.

You need to use the variable like this, if `x` contains the column name:

```
rs2(x).Value = RWPSheetvalues(0)
```